# How to get window.scrollTop, ScrollY or any other distance value when using css scroll snap

Tags: javascript, css, scroll-snap

I am using css scroll snap to scroll through  that are 100vh in height.  The scroll snap works beautifully.

That said I need to determine how far the site visitor has scrolled for a few different reasons.

I have tried:

```
let wrapper = document.getElementById('landing-page-wrapper');
console.log(wrapper.offsetTop);
console.log(window.scrollY);
```

I have also tried window.scrollTop, wrapper.scrollTop and more.

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ravennainteractive/pen/qBPePMJ) of what I am seeing

How can I know the distance scrolled while using 100vh sections and css scroll-snap

TIA

Comment: Are you listening to the `scroll` event on the scrollable element? You probably need to show us more code: see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Consider adding a *runnable* [mcve]. We have no way of knowing how you implemented scroll snap and what *"beautifully"* translates to, in technical terms. It's also not clear what you expect. We need input, current output and expected output to be able to help.

Comment: @Terry edited with a codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your shared code, the reason why `window.onscroll` does not work as expected is because neither `window` nor `document.body` are overflowing vertically. Only the element that is overflowing will fire the scroll event, and in this case it is actually the element that matches the `.box-wrapper` selector.

Therefore if you listen to the scroll event on that element, then you should be able to retrieve its vertical scroll position using [`event.currentTarget.scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop):

```
document.querySelector(".box-wrapper").addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.scrollTop);
});
```

See proof-of-concept example: